# GORM createCriteria() "AND" issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

2 domain classes, person and attribute

```
class Person {
static hasMany = [attributes : Attribute]    


}


class Attribute{
String key
String value
}
```

query for fname:

```
def c = Person.createCriteria()
def result = c.list{

attributes {
          eq("key", "fname")
          eq("value", "foo")
}   


println result
}
```

Result:
[foo foo
,foo bar]

query for lname:

```
def c = Person.createCriteria()
def result = c.list{

attributes {
          eq("key", "lname")
          eq("value", "bar")
}   


println result
}
```

Result:
[bar bar
,foo bar]

query for lname OR fname:

```
def c = Person.createCriteria()
def result = c.list{
or{
attributes {
          eq("key", "fname")
          eq("value", "foo")
}

attributes {
          eq("key", "lname")
          eq("value", "bar")
}
}

println result
}
```

Result:
[foo foo
,foo bar
,bar bar]

but if i change OR to And, i get no results:

```
def c = Person.createCriteria()
def result = c.list{
and{
attributes {
          eq("key", "fname")
          eq("value", "foo")
}

attributes {
          eq("key", "lname")
          eq("value", "bar")
}
}

println result
}
```

Result:
[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty work-around for this:

```
 def list1= Person.createCriteria().list { 
            attributes { 
                    eq("key", "fname") 
                    eq("value", "foo") 
            } 
        } 
def list2= Person.createCriteria().list { 
            attributes { 
                    eq("key", "lname") 
                    eq("value", "bar") 
            } 
        } 
        return list1.intersect(list2)
```

[Source](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Criteria-Builder-how-to-query-multiple-matching-items-in-associated-list-td1367989.html)

I'll leave this question unanswered, hopefully someone will come up with something better